# ADO.net Data Model Best Practice

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, entity-framework-5

I've been working some time now with ADO.net Data Models (in ASP.net). But I'm not sure, that I use it correctly.

for example, I have my Model, "SqlEntities.edmx" and I try to simplify the access.
I created a class called "EH" (for Entity Helper), kinda looks like this

```
private static class EH
{
    private static SqlEntities _Sql = new SqlEntities();

    public static List<User> Users
    { get { return _Sql.Users.ToList(); } }

    public static void Save(this object o)
    {
        DbSet entities = _Sql.Set(o.GetType());
        entities.Add(o);
        _Sql.SaveChanges();
    }

    public static void Delete(this object o)
    {
        DbSet entities = _Sql.Set(o.GetType());
        entities.Remove(o);
        _Sql.SaveChanges();
    }

    public static void Update()
    {
        _Sql.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

First I tried to use it, where I needed it, like:

```
using(SqlEntities sql = new SqlEntities())
{
    User uTemp = new User()
    {
        Name = "Foo"
    };
    sql.Users.Add(uTemp);
    sql.SaveChanges();
}
```

But I had a scope problem, so I switched to my static class.

My concerns are, that this method uses to much of my servers memory space.

Now my question is: Is there a better way to use the datamodel with ASP.

**EDIT:**

To make my question more specific.

How do you use the data model? Is my solution practical?

Comment: Can you make your question more specific?  In its current form, it's really unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Also you should tag this as EF.